# EDID problem with different monitors

Tags: hdmi, config.txt

I've got 2 monitors I use with a pi. The HP monitor self identifies

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# tvservice -n
device_name=HWP-HP_L1755
```

& it is happy with the preferred hdmi settings

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# tvservice -s
state 0x120006 [DVI DMT (35) RGB full 5:4], 1280x1024 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
```

the other 1024x600 monitor doesn't identify

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# tvservice -n
[E] No device present
```

& so I can't use something like

```
[EDID=No device present]
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt=1024 600 60 6 0 0 0    #1024x600 7"
```

in /boot/config.txt to identify it & apply it's hdmi settings. Can anyone see a way to load the the alternate set of hdmi settings when the pi boots with the 1024x600 monitor? I've tried things like

```
[EDID!=HWP-HP_L1755]
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt=1024 600 60 6 0 0 0    #1024x600 7"
```

but so far no joy.